# Missing Virtual Register Numbers in LLVM IR

Tags: llvm, llvm-clang, llvm-ir, register-allocation

Consider the following two examples:

```
int test_plus(int a, int b)
{
  int c = a + b;
  return c;
}

int reg_incr(int a)
{
  int b = a + 1;
  return b;
}
```

The LLVM IR would be:

```
; Function Attrs: nounwind ssp uwtable
define i32 @test_plus(i32, i32) #0 {
  %3 = alloca i32, align 4
  %4 = alloca i32, align 4
  %5 = alloca i32, align 4
  store i32 %0, i32* %3, align 4
  store i32 %1, i32* %4, align 4
  %6 = load i32, i32* %3, align 4
  %7 = load i32, i32* %4, align 4
  %8 = add nsw i32 %6, %7
  store i32 %8, i32* %5, align 4
  %9 = load i32, i32* %5, align 4
  ret i32 %9
}

; Function Attrs: nounwind ssp uwtable
define i32 @reg_incr(i32) #0 {
  %2 = alloca i32, align 4
  %3 = alloca i32, align 4
  store i32 %0, i32* %2, align 4
  %4 = load i32, i32* %2, align 4
  %5 = add nsw i32 %4, 1
  store i32 %5, i32* %3, align 4
  %6 = load i32, i32* %3, align 4
  ret i32 %6
}
```

In the first function, register `%2` is missing (`%0` and `%1` are used for arguments);

Similarly, in the second function, register `%1` is missing.

Just curious, what are the missing ones used for? why are they not consistent?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51793624/llvm-value-of-pointer-operation

Answer (score 0):

I believe `#0` refers to the function itself. and `#1/#2` refers to the arguments